# Cache urls without opening them android

Tags: android, caching, webview

Is it possible to cache a list of website urls, image urls etc without opening them first in a webview? I have a list of img urls coming from a feed that i want to cache on download. i have already posted a question about this but have gotten no response here is my previous question. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831464/cache-image-urls-android)

Comment: This is how:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to drop things into the WebView's cache directly. The only way that would not require preloading in an "off-screen" WebView (which is [totally possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21831532/2977376), btw.) would be to download the images yourself and serve them back to the WebView using [shouldInterceptRequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29).

I would recommend caution with the shouldInterceptRequest-based approach though. It's easy to hurt performance when using shouldInterceptRequest (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19896918/2977376)). Also, you need to take care of removing stale images from your 'cache'.